# Form Submission with JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to make a JSP that will insert a record submitted through a form. However, I'm trying to make sure it connects and by doing so using a mySQL select statement to retrieve data. I posted the error below. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. So far I have this

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String url = "jdbc:mysql//sql.njit.edu:3306/user";
String user = "u";
String pass = "p";
String classPath = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try{
    Class.forName(classPath);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query = "SELECT * FROM Music";

try{
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        out.println(rs.getString("song"));
    }
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        if (stmt != null)
            stmt.close();
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
%>
```

I get the following error

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:451)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:64)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC URL format is wrong. It should be like

```
jdbc:mysql//sql.school.edu:3306/user
```

Comment: Well, instead of printing the stack trace in the catch, print the catch block identifier (sat 'failed during getting conn') and find out where it failed. that would give you more insight.